# Problems when applying function with multiple arguments to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function that checks co-occurring words in a string of text. I would like to use this function in a pandas dataframe so that I can check if there are co-occurrences within sentences of different documents. Unfortunately, the way I passed the function in a pandas dataframe seems to not work properly.

The following code checks if any word in list 'bag1' occurs near ('dist = 4') a word from list 'bag2' in the string called 'sentence'. If there is a co-occurrence, the code prints True. *This code works fine.*

```
import re
import itertools
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
sentence = "The plant is growing at a rapid rate. But the beans are growing slowly."
sentence = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', sentence).lstrip().lower()
words = word_tokenize(sentence)

bag1 = ["plant", "beans", "banana", "apple"]                  
bag2 = ["growing", "fast", "fruit"]
dist = 4

def get_distance(lst1, lst2, dist):
   lst1 = [i for i in lst1 if i.lower() in words]
   lst2 = [i for i in lst2 if i.lower() in words]
   combinations = list(itertools.product(lst1, lst2))
   for w1, w2 in combinations:
       if w1 in words and w2 in words:
           w1_indexes = [index for index, value in enumerate(words) if value == w1]    
           w2_indexes = [index for index, value in enumerate(words) if value == w2]    
           distances = [abs(item[0] - item[1]) for item in itertools.product(w1_indexes, w2_indexes)]
           if min(distances) <= dist:
               print(True)
               break
           else:
               print(False)


def main():
   get_distance(bag1, bag2, dist)

main()
```

Here I am passing the 'get_distance' function to check if any word in list 'bag1' occurs near a word from list 'bag2' in the individual sentences of each document. If there is a co-occurrence, I would like to mark the column 'Match?' as True. Unfortunately, *this code does not work properly.* The problems seem to start at 'lst1 = [i for i in lst1 if i.lower() in row.tokens]' , which somehow generate and empty list. Even if I remove the line of code, there seems to be some bug with the remaining code (see descriptions below).

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import itertools
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

dataset = {
   "document": ["doc1", 'doc2'], 
   "text": ['The plant is growing at a rapid rate. But the beans are growing slowly.', 'The beans are are growing fast in the region.'], 
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)

bag1 = ["plant", "beans", "banana", "apple"]                  
bag2 = ["growing", "fast", "fruit"]
dist = 4

def clean_text():
   df['text'] = df.text.str.lower()
   df['text'] = df.text.str.replace('\ufeff','')
   df['text'] = df.text.str.strip()
   
def split_sentences():
   global df
   df["sentences"] = df["text"].apply(nltk.sent_tokenize)
   df = df.explode('sentences')
   
def tokenize_words():
   df['words_in_text'] = df['sentences'].apply(word_tokenize)
   
def get_distance(row, lst1, lst2, dist):
   row.tokens = df["words_in_text"]
   # It seems that the two lines below generate empty lists. The rest of the code does not work even if I remove the following two lines  
   lst1 = [i for i in lst1 if i.lower() in row.tokens] 
   lst2 = [i for i in lst2 if i.lower() in row.tokens]
   combinations = list(itertools.product(lst1, lst2))
   for w1, w2 in combinations:
       if w1 in row.tokens and w2 in row.tokens:
           w1_indexes = [index for index, value in enumerate(row.tokens) if value == w1]    
           w2_indexes = [index for index, value in enumerate(row.tokens) if value == w2]    
           distances = [abs(item[0] - item[1]) for item in itertools.product(w1_indexes, w2_indexes)]
          if min(distances) <= dist:
              return True
              break
          else:
              return False

#despite having a return value in the get_distance, the values in the 'Match?' column are all 'none'

def main():
   clean_text()
   split_sentences()  
   tokenize_words()
   df['Match?'] = df.apply(get_distance, args=(bag1, bag2, dist), axis=1)
   display(df)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Clearly, I am doing something wrong when using the 'get_distance' function in a pandas dataframe. Please, let me know if you can spot the mistakes. Thank you.

Comment: Please give a clearer description of the problem than "Unfortunately, this code does not work properly", as that is not much to go on. Also, you have no return statement in your `get_distance()` function so I imagine `df['Match?']` won't have anything in it.

Comment: @FiddleStix thanks for pointing the lack of return. I fixed the code, but `get_distance` is still not returning a True or False value. Instead, the `Match?` column shows the value `none`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you wanted something closer to

```python
def get_distance(row, lst1, lst2, dist):
    
    row_tokens = row.words_in_text
    # It seems that the two lines below generate empty lists. The rest of the code does not work even if I remove the following two lines  
    lst1 = [i for i in lst1 if i.lower() in row_tokens] 
    lst2 = [i for i in lst2 if i.lower() in row_tokens]
    combinations = list(itertools.product(lst1, lst2))
    for w1, w2 in combinations:
        if w1 in row_tokens and w2 in row_tokens:
            w1_indexes = [index for index, value in enumerate(row_tokens) if value == w1]    
            w2_indexes = [index for index, value in enumerate(row_tokens) if value == w2]    
            distances = [abs(item[0] - item[1]) for item in itertools.product(w1_indexes, w2_indexes)]
            if min(distances) <= dist:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

I would also suggest

1. Avoiding `global`. If you have to use it, that's a clue that you should redesign your function.
2. Instead, take the df as arguments to your functions
3. Therefore, don't refer to the global `df` at all in your functions
4. In fact, get rid of a global df all together
5. And use black to auto-format your code
6. And use isort to auto-format your imports
7. And use flake8 to find common errors

```python
import itertools

import nltk
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

dataset = {
    "document": ["doc1", "doc2"],
    "text": [
        "The plant is growing at a rapid rate. But the beans are growing slowly.",
        "The beans are are growing fast in the region.",
    ],
}

bag1 = ["plant", "beans", "banana", "apple"]
bag2 = ["growing", "fast", "fruit"]
dist = 4


def clean_text(df):
    df["text"] = df.text.str.lower()
    df["text"] = df.text.str.replace("\ufeff", "")
    df["text"] = df.text.str.strip()


def split_sentences(df):
    df["sentences"] = df["text"].apply(nltk.sent_tokenize)
    return df.explode("sentences")


def tokenize_words(df):
    df["words_in_text"] = df["sentences"].apply(word_tokenize)


def get_distance(row, lst1, lst2, dist):

    # We want the words_in_text for this row, not the whole df
    row_tokens = row.words_in_text

    lst1 = [i for i in lst1 if i.lower() in row_tokens]
    lst2 = [i for i in lst2 if i.lower() in row_tokens]
    combinations = list(itertools.product(lst1, lst2))
    for w1, w2 in combinations:
        if w1 in row_tokens and w2 in row_tokens:
            w1_indexes = [
                index for index, value in enumerate(row_tokens) if value == w1
            ]
            w2_indexes = [
                index for index, value in enumerate(row_tokens) if value == w2
            ]
            distances = [
                abs(item[0] - item[1])
                for item in itertools.product(w1_indexes, w2_indexes)
            ]
            if min(distances) <= dist:
                return True
            else:
                return False


def main():
    my_df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
    clean_text(my_df)
    my_df = split_sentences(my_df)
    tokenize_words(my_df)
    my_df["Match?"] = my_df.apply(get_distance, args=(bag1, bag2, dist), axis=1)
    print(my_df)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```